# Static class template instance as member causes unresolved external symbol error

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class for a stack (on which I can perform push/pop operations).

If I call the `doSomething()` function via

```
A::doSomething();
```

I get an "unresolved external symbol..." error message. How can I create an static stack in my class a on which I can perform push and pop operations?

```
class A {
    private:
        // stack which can hold 4 integers
        static stack<int, 4> s;

    public:
        static void doSomething() {
            s.push(4);
        }
};
```

**You can see a code snippet here: codeshare.io/arJmmY**

Comment: No idea until you've shown a [mcve], but the combination of templates and linker errors hints at a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/3233393).

Comment: You can see a code snippet here: https://codeshare.io/arJmmY

Comment: The type has nothing to do with it. You would see the same problem if the member were an `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

```
class A {
   private:
      static stack<int, 4> s;

    // ...
};
```

you declare the static member `s` of the class `A`.

You have also to **define** it.

You have to add

```
stack<int, 4> A::s;
```

after the `A` body.